# Opencv 3.0 - module object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, sift, surf

I have shifted from OpenCV 2.4.9 to 3.0 to make use of `drawMatches` and `drawMatchesKnn` function. I came to know that it does not come along with non-free algorithms like SIFT , SURF. So I installed *opencv_contrib* from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib by following steps

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/zealous/Downloads/opencv_contrib-master/modules /usr/local ..

make -j5

make install
```

I also cross checked in modules of *opencv*, *xfeatures2d* was there. Then when I tried to do

```
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.xfeatures2d)
```

It gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    help(cv2.xfeatures2d)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

What am I doing wrong here. Just FYI that I am using OpenCV 3.0 beta version . has OpenCV deactivated python wrappers for *xfeatures2d* or I have not installed it correct way?

Comment: try a `cv2.__version__` to see, if it's really using your new cv2.pyd

Comment: Thanks for comment , the opencv package I was trying for was downloaded from opencv official website.. I just downloaded latest code from github for opencv and installed it. It is working fine now with opencv-contrib..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am writing down an answer to my own question, as it might help somebody fixing the same issue.

The opencv package I was trying for was downloaded from opencv **official website**. I just downloaded latest code from **github** for opencv and installed it. It is working fine now with opencv-contrib.