# add extra modules to opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem in python opencv!

I want  to use SIFT algorithm which is not a default algorithm in opencv package. So I have to build OpenCV with extra modules as bellow:

You can build OpenCV, so it will include the modules from this repository. Here is the CMake command for you:

```
$ cd <opencv_build_directory>
$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
$ make -j5
$ make install
```

---

I did all these steps and it was successfully build. But I'm getting error when I call sub modules of opencv (e.g. xfeatures2d, objdetect). I tried using following code;

```
$ import cv2
$ x = cv2.xfeatures2d()
```

It gives me error that `"module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'".`

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencv 3.0 - module object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713312/opencv-3-0-module-object-has-no-attribute-xfeatures2d)

Comment: @Mitty can you please tell me how I can find opencv_source_directory? or what it is? so that I can use Cmake GUI!

Comment: Check if you have followed the installation instructions here,
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: And which OS are you using?.

Comment: the link that you gave I have read several times. I want exactly to know what they mean by `opencv_source_directory`? what should I give there? please help..

Comment: I assume you already downloaded the opencv_contrib abd extracted it or cloned it. But you have to create another directory for building that opencv_contrib. Here the source directory means the path where you have downloaded and stored the opencv_contrib.

Comment: and so what should I write for the first one in the above second line( `opencv_contrib`)?. since I put the opencv downloaded directory for the second one and `opencv_contrib` directory for the first one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download opencv_contrib from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git)
2. Download opencv from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git)
3. Now create a new directory called `opencv_build`
4. Now go to `opencv_build` directory
5. Here `<opencv_contrib>` points to downloaded folder from step 1
6. And `<opencv_source_directory>` points to downloaded folder from step 2
7. Substitute their paths in your cmake command.

Comment: opencv and opencv_contrib have to be in opencv_build folder?