# "Configuring incomplete " installing opencv contrib

Tags: python, opencv, surf

Recently I want to work with SURF in opencv, but when I instelled I don't activate the option to have access to the extra modules. So, I donwloaded from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib and then, I followed the steps for installation in: 
[add extra modules to opencv python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578842/add-extra-modules-to-opencv-python) 
But when I ran the commands for the first time I got:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message): In-source builds are not allowed” in cmake

I was read some about it and the problem cames from **CMakeCache.txt** and has to be removed. I did it and the installation begins, but when finished my terminal shows:

> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
>   See also "/home/chacho/opencv_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
>   See also "/home/chacho/opencv_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"

Finally I can not run the last step. Which is the best option?...try to fixed or uninstall and install again. I don't know what I did wrong. 
Notes:

- I have opencv 4.1.2 version
- I use Ubuntu 18.04
- I work on Spyder

Comment: You probably trying to create the build files at the same directory as the source files, if you are using the GUI just make sure you choose different directories, if you are using the CLI just create new directory outside the source directory and run  the CMake command from inside it.

Comment: Is this the right way to installed? Or there is a better option? Because I've been trying a lot

Comment: Your first error message suggests that you are building inside the main source directory instead of a directory one level up like `source/build`. Your second error suggests that you are building outside of the source directory entirely, and CMake can't find the lists presumably. You want to create a build dir inside source, and build from there. I would suggest following the tutorial from pyimagesearch: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/